# Set up CentOS6 Web Server on local network, but unable to view websites on it?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, webserver

I've set up a web server on our workplace domain. The server has been configured so that Apache works on it and everything seems to be working fine.

However, I am struggling to access the machine via a web browser. I've typed in the IP address of the machine, and the browser comes back saying the page can't be displayed. I've also tried pinging the IP address of the machine and I do get a response back.

I've also checked to see if Apache (httpd) is running, and I can confirm it is. Here is the hosts file held on the server (the domain is company.internal):

> 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 
>   ::1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
>   192.168.1.10 localhost redrum.company.internal

I have also edited the httpd.conf file by adding this:

> ServerName 192.168.1.10:80

What else could be causing the problem?

**EDIT**
I ran `netstat` and the only entry for `httpd` is set to listen. Using the command `fuser 80/tcp` I got this information:

> 80/tcp: 1476  1478 1479 1480 1482 1483 1484 1485 1486

I then ran `ps aux | grep 1476 | grep -v grep` which returned:

> root 1476 0.0 3.7 432020 18912 ?  Ss 12:00 0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd

Then finally ran `pgrep httpd` which returned this:

> 1476 
>   1478 
>   1479 
>   1480 
>   1481 
>   1482 
>   1483 
>   1484 
>   1485 
>   1486

So `httpd` is running and listening on port 80.

**EDIT 2:**
I've ran the `netstat -an | grep :80` and this returned the following information:

> tcp  0   0   :::80    :::*    LISTEN

Comment: Check to see what port and IP address Apache's listening socket is bound to. (Use `netstat`.)

Comment: I've updated the question with the new information.

Comment: We need to see what port and IP address Apache's listening socket is bound to. You can find the output in `netstat -an | grep :80`

Comment: Question has been updated :)

Comment: The listening socket looks right. My next guess would be either a firewall (on the server) or a proxy (configured on the client).

Comment: The firewall has been disabled on the server, I will now check the proxy on the web browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure it's a firewall (as David Schwartz mentioned). CentOS iptables doesn't allow HTTP access by default. Please run `iptables -F` and check if problem still exists. You can edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` to make permanent changes.

Comment: It transpires that the internal firewall to the office was the cause. I added the IP to be bypassed in the browser and it worked. Thank you everyone.

Comment: i had no idea centos 6.8 activated iptables out-of-the-box due to my only experiences being pre-provisioned dedicated servers. `iptables -F` was all it took for my LAN linux box to start serving web sites properly. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but: FWIW, the command you want to answer the question "What's listening on port X?" is lsof.  My usual incantation there is `lsof -i -Pn | grep LISTEN`

-Robin